# igraph fixed node coordinates layout

Tags: r, igraph

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5364376/1317221) really useful.  It helps me plot network/graphs and select the coordinates for the nodes in the plot.

However, the layout rescales the coordinates to -1 to 1.  First off I tried to find out how it does this but couldn't. does it do something like this??

```
(coordinate - mean(coordinates))/(coordinate + mean(coordinates)
```

Second is there a way to keep the original coordinates? I woudl like to plat axes with the graph and so would prefer not to have top rescale everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your first question is in the source code of the `plot.igraph` function; type `plot.igraph` in the R prompt to get the full source code. There is a part in there which says:

```
layout <- layout.norm(layout, -1, 1, -1, 1)
```

`layout.norm` is another function of `igraph` which does the magic for you; type `layout.norm` to see how it works.

Now, the answer to the second question is really simple; just pass `rescale=F` to the arguments of `plot`, which makes `igraph` skip the entire branch in `plot.igraph` where `layout.norm` is called, so it will work with your original coordinates. You can then use `xlim` and `ylim` as usual to set the limits of the X and Y axes.

Comment: great thank you for your help, checking the source now.  The axes limits seem to be tied together though i.e. `ylim=c(0,6)` makes the `xlim` range to 6 too. which is annoying but this is a leap forward, thanks again.

Comment: @user1320502: Set `asp=FALSE` to avoid the default 1:1 aspect ratio.

Comment: Why there is nothing output when I set `rescale=FALSE`?

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented this method with `rescale=FALSE`, and the `xlim, ylim` must be set simultaneously, because the default `xlim and ylim` is `0,1`

Answer (score 0):

```
  set.seed(111)
  ig <- graph_from_data_frame(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters,40,rep=TRUE),nc=2)))
  set.seed(123)
  ig.layout <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(ig)
  rownames(ig.layout) <- V(ig)$name
  par(bg="white",mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))
  plot.igraph(ig,layout=ig.layout,vertex.color=adjustcolor("gray",alpha.f=0.5),rescale=FALSE,xlim=c(4,11),ylim=c(4,11))
  set.seed(321)
  ig.sub <- subgraph(ig,sample(V(ig)$name,5))
  plot.igraph(ig.sub,layout=ig.layout[V(ig.sub)$name,],add=TRUE,vertex.color=adjustcolor("orange",alpha.f=0.5),rescale=FALSE)
```

this code output the graph, where the orange node is the added laterly.

[image]