# How to pass a fixed igraph layout to plot.networx in phangorn?

Tags: r, igraph, phylogeny

Despite the relative popularity of neighborNets, I couldn't find any solutions to the following problem. In R, I'm trying to plot a neighborNet (created using package `phangorn`, object class networx). The package uses `igraph` for plotting static 2D graphs, so every time I re-plot the graph, the layout changes/rotates (default behaviour of `igraph`, apparently). Now, if I were to plot an usual igraph, I'd just save the layout, and then keep re-using it:

```
fixed = layout.sphere(somegraph)
plot(somegraph, layout=fixed)
```

But this doesn't work for the current problem. The help file of plot.networx does refer to igraph and layout, but only in the 'See also' section. Creating a x-y coordinate matrix manually wouldn't work (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364264/how-to-control-the-igraph-plot-layout-with-fixed-positions)), the location of the node labels/tips of nodes is significant on a neighbornet. I tried

```
library("phangorn")
library("igraph")
mydist = dist(matrix(sample(100), ncol=10))  # example data
nnet = neighborNet(mydist)
fixed = layout.sphere(nnet)  # error, Not a graph object
fixed = layout.sphere(as.igraph(nnet))  # doesn't work properly, mangled graph
```

So the question, how to get it working in the vein of

```
plot.networx(nnet, type="2D", layout = fixed)  # ?
```

Comment: would setting a seed work : `set.seed(1); plot.networx(nnet, type="2D") `, This is how approach this with igraph

Comment: @user20650 you'd think so, right, but no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plot.networx` calls `phangorn:::coords` to get the coords which (for 2D) creates an `igraph` object and then uses `layout.kamada.kawai`. This is all hard-coded into `plot.networx` so not flexible enough such that you could use another layout algorithm.

You could follow the code in `phangorn:::coords` to create the graph layout and replace the layout function with another one, and then call `phangorn:::plot2D` with those coords. See `plot.networx` to see how to call `phangorn:::plot2D` correctly.

Comment: I was starting to look into the code as well, but was hoping there would be a "nicer" solution, since this all is actually for pedagodical purposes (I suppose I should have mentioned that). But anyhow, `xy=phangorn:::coords(nnet); phangorn:::plot2D(xy, nnet)` does exactly what I asked for.