# How to set fix node positions with ggnet2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggnet2 to visualize networks and I was wondering whether anyone is aware of a way to fix the node positions as it is possible with e.g. igraph (as explained e.g. here [How to control the igraph plot layout with Fixed Positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364264/how-to-control-the-igraph-plot-layout-with-fixed-positions))

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is an old question but in case anyone looks for the answer...

Make a matrix of the coordinates:

```
l = as.matrix(data.frame(x = c(0.1,0.1, 0.5, 0.8), y = c(0.75, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5)))
```

Use

```
ggnet2(net, mode = l)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem myself and fixed it by setting the random seed. Apparently ggnet2 randomly distributes the nodes in line with the selected algorithm-mode.
So to get reproducible that is to say identical plots just always use `set.seed()` before every plot.

e.g.:

```
set.seed(1)
ggnet2(net)
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabian Sky, I actually used the same hack ... would thus still be helpful to truly fix the node positions